# UbuntuStudio - Sound latency

Tags: sound, virtualbox, ubuntu-studio

I installed UbuntuStudio in a VirtualBox machine and everything works fine except for the sound.

When I go for example to [this](https://pianu.com/test-my-connection) website and I play a note (with the mouse), the key changes it's state to pressed instantly, but I can only hear the sound a few noticeable milliseconds later which is quite annoying.

I think that the problem may be one of two things:

1. The fact that I am running UbuntuStudio in VirtualBox
2. The sound driver

Well, I could try to install UbuntuStudio in the computer itself instead of a virtual machine, but I don't want that, I want to use it in VirtualBox.

In terms of the sound driver, I tried everything but nothing seems to work.

I don't think that the problem is lack of hardware performance because I have a fairly good computer.

Specs of my computer:

> NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M
>
> Intel Core i7 6700HQ
>
> 8Gb DDR4 RAM

And I made available to my virtual machine 4Gb of RAM memory.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Or at least guide me to some path...

Comment: In what operating system is the VM running?

Comment: It's Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Have you considered the option that it may be problem with sound latency in Windows, not the Ubuntu Studio? Have you tried "faster" drivers like ASIO? (I'm not sure if VirtualBox can handle them, though)

Comment: I don't think that the problem is in Windows because I testes the website that I mencioned in Windows and it worked just fine.
I also tried to change the audio controller in VirtualBox settings but it didn't work.
How can I test that ASIO driver? Do I have to install it in Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: Oh, sorry I misread your question a little bit. The (ASIO driver)[http://www.asio4all.com] is meant for Windows. I remember using it back in the times when I had windows, because I was experiencing delay in different music software (for example M1Le). I haven't seen anything like this in my Ubuntu so far, so that's why I supposed Windows may be the issue here.

Comment: Sorry for that malformed link above, here it is: http://www.asio4all.com

Comment: Well, I installed ASIO on Windows and tested Ubuntu and the problem is still there. That didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Is there some way to tell VritualBox what driver to use maybe?

Comment: The only options I have are [this](https://s24.postimg.org/617io7s6d/Sem_T_tulo.png).
If I expand the "Host Audio Driver" I only have one more option which is "Null Audio Driver".

Comment: Did you reboot the PC after installation?

Comment: Yes, I did. Do you think that I have to install WineASIO in Ubuntu?

Comment: I doubt it. If you were running an Windows app in Wine on Ubuntu, then maybe, but it's not the case here.

Comment: Having Ubuntu Studio 16.04 running on real hardware, i tried the website you linked to, and had the same result (delay between visual and audio). Maybe firefox midi-to-audio (I used firefox) is too slow?

Comment: I used chrome, so I don't think it is the problem. I also tested in an LMMS keyboard and also got delay.

Comment: You can try it from a liveCD/usb _(maybe with persistence if usb)_.

Answer (score 2):

Terribly sorry, but it's this specific issue with virtual machines and the high amount of processing that's needed that makes Ubuntu Studio unsupported on virtual machines. There is no way to make a virtual machine's audio latency any lower than what you are experiencing in this use case.

Source: I lead Ubuntu Studio currently.